# Block Email Addresses During Registration Using Rules

Tags: users, rules

I am trying to setup a rule to block all temporary email forwarding domains from being registered on a Drupal site. I have seen the [user restrictions](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_restrictions) module but I would like to do this using rules.

**I'm curious if this is the most efficient way to setup the rule? I'm not sure if account:mail should be used since the account does not exist yet?**

Here is what I have so far:

```
{ "rules_email_domain_name_validation" : {
    "LABEL" : "Email Domain Name Validation",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "email", "validation" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "user_restrictions" ],
    "ON" : { "user_presave" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "text_matches" : {
          "text" : [ "account:mail" ],
          "match" : "(@0815.ru|@0clickemail.com|@0-mail.com|@0wnd.net|@0wnd.org|@10minutemail.com|@20minutemail.com|@2prong.com|@30minutemail.com|@33mail.com|@3d-painting.com|@4warding.com|@4warding.net|@4warding.org|@60minutemail.com|@675hosting.com|@675hosting.net|@675hosting.org|@6ip.us|@6url.com|@75hosting.com|@75hosting.net|@75hosting.org|@7tags.com|@9ox.net|@a-bc.net|@afrobacon.com|@ajaxapp.net|@ama-trade.de|@ama-trans.de|@amilegit.com|@amiri.net|@amiriindustries.com|@anonbox.net|@anonymbox.com|@antichef.com|@antichef.net|@antispam.de|@azmeil.tk|@baxomale.ht.cx|@beefmilk.com|@big-post.com|@binkmail.com|@bio-muesli.net|@bobmail.info|@bodhi.lawlita.com|@bofthew.com|@brefmail.com|@brennendesreich.de|@broadbandninja.com|@bsnow.net|@bugmenot|@bugmenot.com|@bumpymail.com|@bund.us|@casualdx.com|@centermail.com|@centermail.net|@chogmail.com|@choicemail1.com|@cool.fr.nf|@correo.blogos.net|@cosmorph.com|@courriel.fr.nf|@courrieltemporaire.com|@crazymailing.com|@cubiclink.com|@curryworld.de|@cust.in|@dacoolest.com|@dandikmail.com|@dayrep.com|@deadaddress.com|@deadspam.com|@despam.it|@despammed.com|@devnullmail.com|@dfgh.net|@digitalsanctuary.com|@discardmail.com|@discardmail.de|@disposableaddress.com|@disposeamail.com|@disposemail.com|@dispostable.com|@dm.w3internet.co.uk|@dm.w3internet.co.ukexample.com|@dodgeit.com|@dodgit.com|@dodgit.org|@doiea.com|@donemail.ru|@dontreg.com|@dontsendmespam.de|@drdrb.com|@drdrb.net|@dropcake.de|@dumpandjunk.com|@dump-email.info|@dumpmail.de|@dumpyemail.com|@e4ward.com|@email60.com|@emaildienst.de|@emailias.com|@emailigo.de|@emailinfive.com|@emailmiser.com|@emailsensei.com|@emailtemporario.com.br|@emailto.de|@emailwarden.com|@emailx.at.hm|@emailxfer.com|@emeil.ir|@emz.net|@enterto.com|@ephemail.net|@e-postkasten.com|@e-postkasten.de|@e-postkasten.eu|@e-postkasten.info|@etranquil.com|@etranquil.net|@etranquil.org|@evopo.com|@explodemail.com|@faecesmail.me|@fakeinbox.com|@fakeinformation.com|@falseaddress.com|@fastacura.com|@fastchevy.com|@fastchrysler.com|@fastkawasaki.com|@fastmazda.com|@fastmitsubishi.com|@fastnissan.com|@fastsubaru.com|@fastsuzuki.com|@fasttoyota.com|@fastyamaha.com|@filzmail.com|@fizmail.com|@fly-ts.de|@fr33mail.info|@frapmail.com|@front14.org|@fux0ringduh.com|@garliclife.com|@get1mail.com|@get2mail.fr|@getonemail.com|@getonemail.net|@ghosttexter.de|@girlsundertheinfluence.com|@gishpuppy.com|@gowikibooks.com|@gowikicampus.com|@gowikicars.com|@gowikifilms.com|@gowikigames.com|@gowikimusic.com|@gowikinetwork.com|@gowikitravel.com|@gowikitv.com|@great-host.in|@greensloth.com|@grr.la|@gsrv.co.uk|@guerillamail.biz|@guerillamail.com|@guerillamail.net|@guerillamail.org|@guerrillamail.biz|@guerrillamail.com|@guerrillamail.de|@guerrillamail.net|@guerrillamail.org|@guerrillamailblock.com|@h.mintemail.com|@h8s.org|@haltospam.com|@hatespam.org|@hidemail.de|@hochsitze.com|@hotpop.com|@hulapla.de|@ieatspam.eu|@ieatspam.info|@ieh-mail.de|@ihateyoualot.info|@iheartspam.org|@imails.info|@inbax.tk|@inboxalias.com|@inboxclean.com|@inboxclean.org|@incognitomail.com|@incognitomail.net|@incognitomail.org|@insorg-mail.info|@ipoo.org|@irish2me.com|@iwi.net|@jetable.com|@jetable.fr.nf|@jetable.net|@jetable.org|@jnxjn.com|@junk1e.com|@kasmail.com|@kaspop.com|@keepmymail.com|@killmail.com|@killmail.net|@kir.ch.tc|@klassmaster.com|@klassmaster.net|@klzlk.com|@koszmail.pl|@kulturbetrieb.info|@kurzepost.de|@lags.us|@letthemeatspam.com|@lhsdv.com|@lifebyfood.com|@link2mail.net|@litedrop.com|@lol.ovpn.to|@lookugly.com|@lopl.co.cc|@lortemail.dk|@lr78.com|@m4ilweb.info|@maboard.com|@mail.by|@mail.mezimages.net|@mail2rss.org|@mail333.com|@mail-4server.com|@mail4trash.com|@mailbidon.com|@mailblocks.com|@mailcatch.com|@maildrop.cc|@maileater.com|@mailexpire.com|@mailfa.tk|@mailfreeonline.com|@mailimate.com|@mailin8r.com|@mailinater.com|@mailinator.com|@mailinator.net|@mailinator2.com|@mailincubator.com|@mailismagic.com|@mailme.ir|@mailme.lv|@mailmetrash.com|@mailmoat.com|@mailnator.com|@mailnesia.com|@mailnull.com|@mailshell.com|@mailsiphon.com|@mailslite.com|@mailtemp.info|@mail-temporaire.fr|@mailzilla.com|@mailzilla.org|@malahov.de|@mbx.cc|@mega.zik.dj|@meinspamschutz.de|@meltmail.com|@messagebeamer.de|@mierdamail.com|@mintemail.com|@moburl.com|@moncourrier.fr.nf|@monemail.fr.nf|@monmail.fr.nf|@msa.minsmail.com|@mt2009.com|@mt2014.com|@mx0.wwwnew.eu|@mycleaninbox.net|@mymailoasis.com|@mypartyclip.de|@myphantomemail.com|@myspaceinc.com|@myspaceinc.net|@myspaceinc.org|@myspacepimpedup.com|@myspamless.com|@mytrashmail.com|@neomailbox.com|@nepwk.com|@nervmich.net|@nervtmich.net|@netmails.com|@netmails.net|@netzidiot.de|@neverbox.com|@nnot.net|@nobulk.com|@noclickemail.com|@nogmailspam.info|@nomail.xl.cx|@nomail2me.com|@nomorespamemails.com|@no-spam.ws|@nospam.ze.tc|@nospam4.us|@nospamfor.us|@nospamthanks.info|@notmailinator.com|@nowmymail.com|@nurfuerspam.de|@nus.edu.sg|@nwldx.com|@objectmail.com|@obobbo.com|@oneoffemail.com|@onewaymail.com|@online.ms|@oopi.org|@opayq.com|@ordinaryamerican.net|@otherinbox.com|@ourklips.com|@outlawspam.com|@ovpn.to|@owlpic.com|@pancakemail.com|@pimpedupmyspace.com|@pjjkp.com|@politikerclub.de|@poofy.org|@pookmail.com|@privacy.net|@proxymail.eu|@prtnx.com|@punkass.com|@putthisinyourspamdatabase.com|@qq.com|@quickinbox.com|@rcpt.at|@recode.me|@recursor.net|@regbypass.com|@regbypass.comsafe-mail.net|@rejectmail.com|@rklips.com|@rmqkr.net|@rppkn.com|@rtrtr.com|@s0ny.net|@safe-mail.net|@safersignup.de|@safetymail.info|@safetypost.de|@sandelf.de|@saynotospams.com|@selfdestructingmail.com|@sendspamhere.com|@sharklasers.com|@shiftmail.com|@shitmail.me|@shortmail.net|@sibmail.com|@skeefmail.com|@sky-ts.de|@slaskpost.se|@slopsbox.com|@smellfear.com|@snakemail.com|@sneakemail.com|@sofimail.com|@sofort-mail.de|@sogetthis.com|@soodonims.com|@spam.la|@spam.su|@spam4.me|@spamavert.com|@spambob.com|@spambob.net|@spambob.org|@spambog.com|@spambog.de|@spambog.net|@spambog.ru|@spambox.info|@spambox.irishspringrealty.com|@spambox.us|@spamcannon.com|@spamcannon.net|@spamcero.com|@spamcon.org|@spamcorptastic.com|@spamcowboy.com|@spamcowboy.net|@spamcowboy.org|@spamday.com|@spamex.com|@spamfree24.com|@spamfree24.de|@spamfree24.eu|@spamfree24.info|@spamfree24.net|@spamfree24.org|@spamgourmet.com|@spamgourmet.net|@spamgourmet.org|@spamherelots.com|@spamhereplease.com|@spamhole.com|@spamify.com|@spaminator.de|@spamkill.info|@spaml.com|@spaml.de|@spammotel.com|@spamobox.com|@spamoff.de|@spamslicer.com|@spamspot.com|@spamthis.co.uk|@spamthisplease.com|@spamtrail.com|@speed.1s.fr|@supergreatmail.com|@supermailer.jp|@suremail.info|@tagyourself.com|@teewars.org|@teleworm.com|@teleworm.us|@tempalias.com|@tempemail.biz|@tempemail.com|@tempe-mail.com|@tempemail.net|@tempinbox.co.uk|@tempinbox.com|@tempmail.it|@tempmail2.com|@tempomail.fr|@temporarily.de|@temporarioemail.com.br|@temporaryemail.net|@temporaryforwarding.com|@temporaryinbox.com|@thanksnospam.info|@thankyou2010.com|@thisisnotmyrealemail.com|@throwawayemailaddress.com|@tilien.com|@tmailinator.com|@toiea.com|@tradermail.info|@trash2009.com|@trash-amil.com|@trashemail.de|@trashmail.at|@trash-mail.at|@trashmail.com|@trash-mail.com|@trashmail.de|@trash-mail.de|@trashmail.me|@trashmail.net|@trashmail.org|@trashmail.ws|@trashmailer.com|@trashymail.com|@trashymail.net|@trillianpro.com|@tryalert.com|@turual.com|@twinmail.de|@tyldd.com|@uggsrock.com|@upliftnow.com|@uplipht.com|@username.e4ward.com|@username.otherinbox.com|@venompen.com|@veryrealemail.com|@veryrealmail.com|@viditag.com|@viewcastmedia.com|@viewcastmedia.net|@viewcastmedia.org|@webm4il.info|@wegwerfadresse.de|@wegwerfemail.de|@wegwerfmail.de|@wegwerfmail.net|@wegwerfmail.org|@wetrainbayarea.com|@wetrainbayarea.org|@wh4f.org|@whatpaas.com|@whyspam.me|@willselfdestruct.com|@winemaven.info|@wronghead.com|@wuzup.net|@wuzupmail.net|@wwwnew.eu|@xagloo.com|@xemaps.com|@xents.com|@xmaily.com|@xoxy.net|@yep.it|@yogamaven.com|@yopmail.com|@yopmail.fr|@yopmail.net|@ypmail.webarnak.fr.eu.org|@yuurok.com|@zehnminutenmail.de|@zippymail.info|@zoaxe.com|@zoemail.org|@trbvm.com|@20mail.it|@20mail.eu)",
          "operation" : "regex"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "user_restrictions_block_mail" : { "account" : [ "account" ] } } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it using account:mail?

Comment: It seems odd that your action would be user_restrictions_block_mail if you don't want to use the user restrictions module.

Comment: Good point. I was playing around with it so this is as far as I had gotten and discovered there were multiple email tokens which was confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were to do this task I would create a custom hook_form_validate and then add it to the registration form with hook_form_alter

Then in your validate function you can do your custom php in there to check if the email address is what you want. If it's not you can use form_set_error to add an error to the form and that way you can provide a custom message to the user too

Comment: Sounds like a decent approach. Not as generic as rules like I hoped but does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal has a feature that allows you to either completely block or moderate all user registrations by adopting one of them :

1. Core approval features
2. E-mail verification
3. Block certain user details
4. Captchas
5. Honeypots / Secret form fields
6. Block by location
7. Secret codes
8. 3rd party spam tools
9. Delayed roles
10. Warning message

More [Details](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/block-spam-registrations-drupal/)

Comment: This gives vague options but doesn't say how to actually set anything up.

Comment: check link details

Comment: Links without explanation are not ideal because if the link breaks the answer become much less useful to people in future.